# WPF Passing an object from one control to another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to pass an object in one control to another in WPF.  It seems that I am having issue with the binding of the control in the view.

I currently have this:

```
<controls:ConfigControl Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ConfigControl" />
<Label Content="{Binding ConfigControl.JobConfig.JDFPrinterFolder, FallbackValue='didnt work'}"></Label>
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Column="1" >
    <controls:MainControls Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" JobConfig="{Binding ConfigControl.JobConfig}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

I am trying to pass the ConfigControl.JobConfig to my MainControls and I added the label to debug and it always results in "didn't work".  I'm not sure why it's not working, but a point in the right dirrection would help.

on my ConfigControl side I have a public object called JobConfig:

```
public JobConfiguration JobConfig {
    get { return _jobConfig; }
    set {
        _jobConfig = value;
        // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
        OnPropertyChanged("JobConfig");
    }
}
```

And it get's populated in the constructor for ConfigControl:

```
public ConfigControl() {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    LoadSettings();  <--- here
}
```

I have also debugged to make sure that the settings where there.

Inside my MainControls I have this:

```
public JobConfiguration JobConfig {
    get { return (JobConfiguration)GetValue(JobConfigProperty); }
    set { SetValue(JobConfigProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for JobConfig.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty JobConfigProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("JobConfig", typeof(JobConfiguration), typeof(MainControls), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

I have confirmed that the data is set here. And everything works in the ConfigControl view.  Yes I confirmed that JDFPrinterFolder is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ElementBinding.

```
<controls:MainControls Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                       JobConfig="{Binding ElementName=ConfigControl, 
                       Path=JobConfig}" />

<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=ConfigControl, 
                         Path=JobConfig.JDFPrinterFolder, 
                         FallbackValue='didnt work'}" />
```

Comment: Awesome, that works!  But why doesn't the label work?

Comment: Its the same thing do element binding on the label too. Edited my answer